# PushPlugin register function does not give regid

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I have added in `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />` config.xml. When I run the app it shows alert "Callback Success! Result = OK" even when phone is not connected to internet then I press OK and nothing else happens.

onNotificationGCM event does not fire and so it never returns regid.

```
function showAlert(message, title) {
    if (navigator.notification) {
        navigator.notification.alert(message, null, title, 'OK');
    } else {
        alert(title ? (title + ": " + message) : message);
    }
}   

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $(document).ready(function () {navigator.splashscreen.hide();});    

    try {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"659859389520","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});
    } catch (ex) {
        showAlert(ex, 'push error');
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 3000);

}

function successHandler(result) {
    showAlert('Callback Success! Result = '+result, "Success");
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    showAlert(error, "Error");
}

function onNotificationGCM(e) {

    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
        if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
        {
            console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
            showAlert('registration id = '+e.regid);
        }
        break;

        case 'message':

        showAlert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt, "Message");
        break;

        case 'error':
        showAlert('GCM error = '+e.msg, "Error");
        break;

        default:
        showAlert('An unknown GCM event has occurred', "Unknown Event");
        break;
    }
}
```

In the ADB log GCM is working absolutely fine. It is returning a regid perfectly but sendJavascript is not calling my onNotificationGCM function. And therefore it is not working. Why? What I am doing wrong here?

`05-22 01:28:27.407: V/PushPlugin(21372): sendJavascript: javascript:onNotificationGCM({"regid":"APb91bG...Sqg4YP","event":"registered"})`

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I was redirecting from index.html to another page before onNotificationGCM could be called. Therefore it was not being called at all.

To test I placed the redirection code inside onNotificationGCM and it works perfect.